# When performing an .explain() can someone tell me what the nYields field is for?

Tags: mongodb

```
db.update_queue.find().explain();
{
        "cursor" : "BasicCursor",
        "nscanned" : 6046,
        "nscannedObjects" : 6046,
        "n" : 6046,
        "millis" : 5,
        "nYields" : 23,
        "nChunkSkips" : 0,
        "isMultiKey" : false,
        "indexOnly" : false,
        "indexBounds" : {

        }
}
```

`From the net i found out this` :

**nYields is how many times the query was time sliced out.
So that means for this query other queries were let in 23 times.**

```
What does this mean actually ??
```

This is my understanding with respect to the above

**Whether this mean that this query waited  until 23 queries were executed before executing the current query ??**

Comment: [From the docs](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/cursor.explain/#explain.nYields): `"nYields is a number that reflects the number of times this query yielded the read lock to allow waiting writes execute.`"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is down to the concurrency features of MongoDB which have been far more prominent in recent versions. There is a feature of yielding operations which have data out of RAM in exchange for ones that have their data in RAM.

This means that MongoDB is never idle queuing your operations and in general makes for faster operation.

`nYields` denotes how many times this operation fell prey to the concurrency algorithms within MongoDB and so subsided itself for other operations whose data was in RAM.

#### Edit

As an edit, form the doc page: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/faq/concurrency/#does-a-read-or-write-operation-ever-yield-the-lock :

> Long running read and write operations, such as queries, updates, and deletes, yield under many conditions. In MongoDB 2.0, operations yielded based on time slices and the number of operations waiting for the actively held lock.

However:

> After 2.2, more adaptive algorithms allow operations to yield based on predicted disk access (i.e. page faults).

So in cases more than just faulting can effect yielding, but I believe this query was faulting more than anything.

Comment: @PreethiJain To answer another little thing you noted in your question, the operation wil resume once its data is back in RAM

Comment: While you are correct about this being about concurrency it doesn't have anything to do with data being in RAM or not. A yield is when a read query is paused in order to allow a write to the same collection to run.

Comment: @MartinSkøtt That should fix it

Comment: @Sammaye Yes, much better. The concurrency FAQ is quite informative :)

Answer (score 0):

Docs says:

explain.nYields

nYields is a number that reflects the number of times this query yielded the read lock to allow waiting writes execute.

Comment: Could anybody please explain what this mean  in general ??